# ng-repat not working in ng-include angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So just to explain, a little bit closer.
I have 3 controllers, each has a different purpose, in ng-route.
But when I ng-include file in the template file, the second controller's `ng-repeat`  is not working,
on the #/footer with a route. But on the #/nemke everything is working fine.
I know it's confusing. Thanks in advance.

#/footer template

```
<div class="container fluid bigCont" >
<div id="muster">
<span id="left"></span> 
<span id="right"></span>    

<ul class="slide">
<li id="{{image.id}}" class="slides" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(images/' + image.image + ')'}" >
<div class="absolute">  
<h2 class="duka">{{image.text}}</h2>
<p>{{image.text2}}</p>
<button class="main-but" >More</button>
</div>
<span class="closer">X</span>
<span ng-click ="editor()" class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil pencer" aria-hidden="true"></span>

</li>
</ul>
</div>  
<div ng-include="'good.html'"></div> the controller for this tempalte doesen't work goodCtrl
```

#/nemke template

```
 <h1>{{name}}</h1>
    <h1 id="number" ng-click="getNumber(1)">0</h1>
    <form  name="myForm" ng-if="bool" ng-model="formModel">
    <input type="text" ng-model="formModel.text" id="text" name="text" required/>
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="addNew()">Add new text</button>
    </form>
    <button ng-click="boolke=true">Fade in</button>
    <button ng-click="boolke=false">Fade Out</button>
    <p ng-if="boolke" ng-click="deletRec($event)" class="del_id sade" id="{{user.id}}" ng-repeat = "user in users">{{user.text}}</p>
    <p>{{name}}</p>
```

controller for nemke template

```
app.controller('goodCtrl', ['$scope','$http','$controller', 'images', function($scope,$http,$controller, images){
$controller('getCtrl',{$scope:$scope});
$scope.name = "Nikson";
document.getElementById('title').style.display = "none";
images.success(function(data){
$scope.users = data;
});

$scope.formModel = {};

$scope.addNew = function() {
$scope.users.push($scope.formModel);
    /*$http.post('post.php', $scope.formModel).
    success(function(data){
        console.log("ok")
    }).error(function(data){
        console.log("err");
    }); */
$scope.formModel = {}; 

};

$scope.deletRec = function(event) {
var id = event.target.id;
$http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: 'delete.php',
    data: {
        id: id
    },
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
})
.then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}, function(rejection) {
    console.log(rejection.data);
});

event.target.style.display = "none";
}

$scope.care = [
    {
       name:"Nemke",
       age:12, 
    },
    {
        name:"Uros",
        age:13,
    }
]

}]);
```

routing js

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/",{
controller:"newCtrl",
templateUrl:"main.html",
})
.when("/footer",{
controller: "getCtrl",
templateUrl : "red.html",

})
.when("/nemke",{
controller: "goodCtrl",
templateUrl:"good.html",
})
.otherwise({
redirectTo:"/"  
})
});
```

main js

```
app.controller('getCtrl',['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'images', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, images) {
images.success(function(data){
console.log(data);

}]);
```

Comment: Can you make a plunkr which demos this not working?  That will make it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: I figured, out, it' s just easire to use service for this.